# Access standard error on other side of ||?

Tags: bash

I want to do something like:

```
command || log $error_from_last_command
```

Is there a way to use `||` and still access `stderr` like a pipe?

*My intention here is to process the error message from `command`, using `log`, but only if `command` fails.
I'm reading through the marked duplicate but I don't see how to apply that to my situation.*

Comment: Do you mean you want to both run the right-hand side command only if the left-hand side fails, _and_ get the output of the lhs to the rhs? Or something else? I'm not sure what it is you mean, could you clarify this a bit?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes as you describe, `log` should only run if `command` fails. The input of `log` should be the failure message of `command` to be sent to server for reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the output of a program in another that only runs after the first command completed, it's probably easiest to store the output in a file.

```
errfile=$(mktemp)
if ! somecommand 2> "$errfile" ; then
    log < "$errfile"    # or  log "$(cat "$errfile")" ?
fi
rm "$errfile"
```

Piping the output would require the commands to run at the same time, but we only get the exit code when the first command finishes.

`log < "$errfile"` above would of course direct the error message to stdin of `log` (like you'd get with a pipe). To get it as a command line argument, use `log "$(cat "$errfile")"` (one argument), or `log $(cat "$errfile")` (with word splitting, `log` sees multiple arguments), or `log "$(< "$errfile")"` (non-standard, works at least in Bash).

Comment: Ah I see. It works with `cat`, if `log` in an `STDIN`-reader. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it would be sufficient for your purposes to know the *exit code* of the first element of the pipe (or any element of any pipe), you can avail yourself of the `bash` variable `PIPESTATUS`, which according to the `bash` man page is: "An  array  variable ... containing a list of exit status values from the processes in  the  most-recently-executed foreground pipeline ...".

I realize that technically you are asking for something a bit different, but you might consider whether using this variable might meet your need in a way you didn't originally anticipate.